# Cannot update my list in C, problems with pointers

Tags: c, list, pointers, reference

I want to update a list in C but it seems not to be affected by a function call. This is my piece of code:

```
void bswabe_update_key( bswabe_msk_t** msk, bswabe_pub_t* pub, bswabe_upd_t** upd) {
    element_t beta;
    unsigned current_version = 0;
    
    /* initialize */
    bswabe_upd_t* new_node = malloc(sizeof(bswabe_upd_t));
    element_init_Zr(beta, pub->p);
    element_init_G1(new_node->u_cp, pub->p);
    bswabe_upd_t *current_node = *upd;
    element_random(beta);
    
    /* compute */
    while ( current_node != NULL && current_node->next != NULL) {
      current_node = current_node->next;
      current_version++;
    }
    
    if(current_node == NULL)
      new_node->u_msk_s = 1;
    else
        new_node->u_msk_s = current_node->u_msk_s+1;
    
    element_invert(new_node->u_cp, (*msk)->beta);
    element_printf("Version %d: %B\n", new_node->u_msk_s, new_node->u_cp);
    
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if (current_node != NULL)
      current_node->next = new_node;
    else
     *upd = new_node;
}
```

The list that I want to create/update is inside the `bswabe_upd_t` structure:

```
struct bswabe_upd_s{
    element_t u_cp;    /* Z_r */
    /* version */
    unsigned u_msk_s; 
    struct bswabe_upd_s* next;
    
};
typedef struct bswabe_upd_s bswabe_upd_t;
```

The `element_init_xx` and the `element_invert` (both defined in PBC library) are `void element_invert(element_t n, element_t a);` and `element_init_xx(element_t e, pairing_t pairing);`
This is the call in the main function:

```
int main(){
    bswabe_pub_t* pub;
    bswabe_msk_t* msk;
    
    bswabe_upd_t* upd;

    parse_args(argc, argv);

    bswabe_setup(&pub, &msk);
    
    bswabe_update_key( &msk, pub, &upd);
    bswabe_update_key( &msk, pub, &upd);
    bswabe_update_key( &msk, pub, &upd);
    bswabe_update_key( &msk, pub, &upd);
    bswabe_update_key( &msk, pub, &upd);
    bswabe_update_key( &msk, pub, &upd);
}
```

I precise that `bswabe_setup` works correctly. Lastly this is what it comes out when I execute it:

```
Version 1: O
Version 2: O
Version 3: O
Version 4: O
Version 5: O
Version 6: O
```

That is not a 0 but a "O" character (from the initialization)

Comment: `upd` in `main` seems to be uninitialized.

Comment: `beta` in `bswabe_update_key` also seems to be uninitialized.